# Android onKeyDown and onKeyUp event firing twice

Tags: android

I have searched and searched and found nothing that fully explains whats happening. Basically both the onKeydown and onKeyUp event are firing twice. In Android 4.1 I am not having any issues but this one customer upgraded to Android 4.2.2 and the problem started. I can not find anything in the documentation indicating a change but I have found that this was an issue in Android 2.x

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    char pressedKey = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();
    String TAG = null;
    if (event != null && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown - keyCode = " + keyCode);
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            {
                if(currentOrderLineDetailCollection.size()>0)
                {
                    DisplayRemoveAlert(this);
                }
            }
            default:
                char stkeyCode = pressedKey;    
                UPCNum += stkeyCode;
        }
    }

    if (UPCNum.length() >= 12) {
        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(OrderDetail_Activity.this, HandheldScanner_Activity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("UPCNum", UPCNum.trim());
        startActivity(intent1);
        UPCNum="";
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the repeat value in the event?

Comment: No I had not been but I just implemented it and it is still repeating the characters. I am using a bluetooth barcode scanner but I don't think that is the problem as I do not have the same issue on Android 4.1.

Comment: So I tested this theory in the Android VM and I am not seeing it happen there. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I would agree the input device probably isn't the problem. If you are checking repeat count (like I added here) and still getting repeated values, then I'll need more info to help. Perhaps print out all the values from get methods for the event in the logcat...

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for but this is the only event and all the associated code with the event. Basically the scanner acts like a keyboard and so keydown/keyup gets fired for each number of the barcode. The output I am getting is the first 6 digits of the upc number with each number duplicated IE barcode 0123456789012 would return 001122334455 because it then meets my UPCNum.length() check. If I remove that check I get the full 12 digit barcode with each character duplicated.

Comment: I understand the goal and the problem, so no worries there. I'm just looking for more info about what's in the KeyEvent object to help determine how you can discern which events you need to pay attention to. I'm asking for you to add logcat output for the methods in KeyEvent, like getFlags(), getMetaState(), getSource(), getScanCode(), getRepeatCount(), etc. because there has to be something that distinguishes the firing of each event.

Comment: Kind of annoying I have the exact same problem. I am listening on onKeyUp from a bluetooth scanner which is paired as a keyboard and the onKeyUp event gets fired twice with the Motorolla CS3070, I am trying to figure out what's wrong too (I am testing on Jelly Bean)